# Как правильно говорить - заявление на отгула или отгулы?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно говорить - заявление на отгула или отгулы?

Comment: @Оксанчик, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

На отгулА??? Нет, так нельзя. )))))))

Comment: А если множественное число, то заявление на отгулы? Ударение в слове отгулы на какую букву? На у?

Comment: @Niemand, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Answer (score 1):

Хотя фраза носит разговорный оттенок, тем не менее правильно: заявление об отгуле.

Дополнение

О́ТГУЛ, отгула, ***мн. нет, муж***. (прост. и обл.). Действие по гл. отгулять во 2 и 3 знач. - отгуливать.***(Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940)***.

ОТГ***У***Л, -а; м.
1.
к Отгулять - отгуливать и Отгуляться - отгуливаться (2 зн.). Летний о. скота. Пустить коней на о. в луга.
2.
Отпуск, свободный от работы день (дни), предоставляемые за сверхурочную работу. Предоставить, дать, взять, получить о. Быть в отгуле. Воспользоваться отгулом для уборки квартиры. < Отгульный, -ая, -ое. Разг. (2 зн.). О. день. О. отпуск.( Б***ольшой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.
Первое издание: СПб.: Норинт, 1998.
Публикуется в авторской редакции 2009 года).***

Comment: А если множественное число, то заявление на отгулы? Ударение в слове отгулы на какую букву? На у?

Comment: У слова "отгул'' мн.ч. нет. ОтгУл (отпуск); Отгул(отзвук).

Comment: Огромное спасибо.

Comment: Интересно, кто это придумал, что мн. числа у слова *отгул* - НЕТ? Копирую статью из Словаря 1847 :  
>**Отгулъ**... Тоже, что отгуливанiе. *Частые отгулы не доводятъ до добра.*

Comment: Словарь 1806-22 :  
[Отгулъ](http://slovari.pro/russkie/slovari/tolkovie/akademii-1806-1822_vol-4/slovar-akad-alf-4/257.html)  
Сам Пушкин еще отгулы брал...

Comment: В настоящее время у слова отгул нет мн.ч. Встречающееся у Пушкина мн.ч. может быть оправдано стилистическими целями.

Comment: Есть отгулы. Никуда они с начала 19 века и по сию пору не делись.  
>В. Ф. Панова. Ясный берег (1949)  
― А ты в рабочий сезон устраиваешь себе отгулы.

>Валентин Распутин. Наташа (1981)  
Конечно, у нее могли скопиться отгулы за внеочередные дежурства, она могла заболеть, много чего могло быть, но я уже чувствовал, что все это не то.

Comment: > В настоящее время у слова отгул нет мн.ч.

Для меня в этой теме - сплошные неожиданности. :-)

Я 150 раз слышал на работе слово **"отгУлы"** во множественном числе. Когда на заводе работал. Мне почему-то кажется, что на любом заводе говорят что-то вроде **"заработать отгулы"** (в смысле, множ. число). 

.

А вот **"отгулА"**, как в вопросе **Оксанчик**, слышать ни разу не приходилось. Даже любопытно стало, в каких краях так говорят? Я совершенно без негатива интересуюсь, если что... мы сами провинциальные :-)

Comment: Викисловарь:

ед. ч. **отгу́л** ; мн. ч. **отгу́лы**.

https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB

Comment: >В настоящее время у слова отгул нет мн.ч.  
  
Никак не могу согласиться. А почему такое странное утверждение? Ну, словарь - ладно, может и устареть, но живой-то язык требует? "У меня осталось пять неиспользованных отгулов".

Comment: Дело в том, что ни в одном современном словаре не указано мн.ч. , но не оговаривается. Единственный словарь - это словарь Ушакова, где говорится,что слово "отгул" не имеет мн.ч. Даже орфографические словари не указывают,  и не оговаривают мн.ч. Странно. Я задал вопрос Грамоте.ру. От них ответа дождаться сложно. Но буду настаивать.